# *Customization of the guest operating system 'freebsd64Guest' is not supported*

Tags: ansible, vmware, freebsd

While trying to clone VM via ansible using the vmware_guest module, new VM gets created with the old hostname. The Customize option is not taking effect. The error message that i see in the logs as well as within V-center is

*Customization of the guest operating system 'freebsd64Guest' is not supported*.

The operating system is FreeBSD OS. Please note, I have installed openvm tools in the source vm and only then i took a template. So, I have been trying to create the VM from the template that already has openvm tools.

```
---
- name: Create a VM from a template
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
    username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
    password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
    validate_certs: '{{ validate_certs }}'
    name: '{{ vm_name }}'
    state: '{{ state }}'
    template: '{{ vm_template }}'
    datacenter: '{{ cluster_name }}'
    folder: '{{ folder_name }}'
    cluster: '{{ cluster }}'
    hardware:
      memory_mb: '{{ ram }}'
      num_cpus: '{{ cpu }}'
      scsi: '{{ scsi }}'
    customization:
      hostname: '{{ vm_name }}'
    networks:
    - name: VM-NETWORK
      ip: '{{ ip_address }}'
      netmask: '{{ netmask }}'
      gateway: '{{ gateway }}'
      type: '{{ type }}'
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy
~
```

Comment: What version of vSphere? And, have you tried doing the clone manually?

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thank you for your comments. I use vcenter 6.x version.As mentioned earlier cloning VM works manually as well using Ansible. Only problem is, when I try to use customization by setting the new hostname for the host, it does not reflect. For now, I had to shutdown the source host, ssh to the new host and change the ip and hostname to new one and restart it.

Comment: Raised bug in Ansible - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/43189

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, it's a bug/feature that's not currently available in Vmware itself for FreeBSD. Please see the matrix available -

http://partnerweb.vmware.com/programs/guestOS/guest-os-customization-matrix.pdf

I have received this info, after raising bug in

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/43189#issuecomment-407339134